# Flask session and multiple users

Tags: python, session, flask

```
@app.route('/login', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      session['username'] = request.form['username']
      return redirect(url_for('index'))
   return '''
```

This is the "template" for a flask session login. My question is,

```
'username'
```

is mapped to **only one** value which is the `request.form['username']`

So what if I have two users login,

```
(1) 'jack'
```

So now `session['username'] = jack`

And then

```
(2) 'davis'
```

So now `session['username'] = davis`

But then jack is not logged in anymore. How do I do this?

Comment: session is a cookie stored on the clients computer, so this isn't an issue

Comment: The [session object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#sessions) is specific to the user and stored in a signed cookie on the user's machine.

Comment: Reference: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_sessions.htm

Comment: This code works but it uses `flask.login` : https://github.com/shekhargulati/flask-login-example

Answer (score 1):

It works. Just test the users (sessions) with at least one user opened in an incognito browser window.

Answer (score 0):

We can use dictionary to keep separate variables and session for different users
eg - >[Demo Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3k0f.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask], or [answer] for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of incognito I use gologin profiles. In their app it is comfortable to view the saved cookies of different browser instances. It works.

Answer (score -1):

***Edited***

Flask session allows only **one** user to be logged in, but you can test your app with many users using following ways (there are some more though):

- use incognito tab, but allows only **2** users to be logged in simultaneously

If you want 3 or more users:

- use **container** tabs in Firefox
- install **MultiLogin** extension or any other similar extension for multiple sessions, if you use Google Chrome for example or any other popular browser

Comment: Are you affiliated with this program? Why does this extension fix the problem? Please elaborate