# Flask. Is it possible to request more data in the middle of a request?

Tags: python, flask

I have a method `.start(phone=phone,code_callback_func=getCode, password_callback_func=getPass)` that takes in a phone number and a func to retrieve a code from client, and a func to get password from client.

This method first uses the phone number to request a code from telegram, then fires the getCode func given, then asks for password through getPass.

**Is it possible in Flask to get another `<form>` from the client in the middle of a Post request from a form?**

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def teleLogin():
    if request.method == "POST":

        phone = request.form.get("phone")

        # Activate telethon login process

        # ...some code...

        client.start(phone=phone, password=get2FA,
                     code_callback=getCode)

    return render_template("tele-login.html")
```

```
<body>
    <div id="forms">
        <form onsubmit="phoneComplete()">
            <label for="phone">Phone Number (with international code)</label>
            <input type="text" autofocus placeholder="Phone" name="phone" id="phone">
            <button type="submit">Request Code</button>
        </form>

        <br><br>
        
        <!-- WANT TO APPEND THIS FORM AFTER PHONE FORM IS SUBMITTED -->
        <!-- <form onsubmit="codeComplete()">
            <label for="code">Code</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Code" name="code" id="code">
            <button type="submit">Submit Code</button>
        </form> -->
        <!-- AND APPEND ANOTHER FORM FOR PASSWORD AFTER CODE IS SENT -->
    </div>
    
    
</body>
```

Comment: no each post would run in its own thread ... they could arrive simultaneously and you could update a file or database the other method could check for or something hacky like that ... you need to think of a different way to solve this i think ...

Comment: I would use a [session variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41865329/flask-session-and-multiple-users) and redirect to a second form. the second form would grab the session variable as part of the request. or, more simply, include everything in the first form

Comment: or, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77248480/flask-returning-400-on-fetch-request), you can create a multipart form with javascript