# Flask returning 400 on fetch request

Tags: python, flask, http-headers, fetch

On my flask application, I have a login route.

```py
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def loginRoute():
    try:
        print(request.headers)
        username = request.form['username']
        passwordUnhashed = request.form['password']
        passwordHashed = hashlib.sha256(passwordUnhashed.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = %s AND Password = %s", (username, passwordHashed))

        if mycursor.fetchone():
            session['user'] = username
            return makeResponseJSON(True)
        else:
            return makeResponseJSON(False, "Incorrect username or password.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return makeResponseJSON(False, str(e))
```

But the problem isn't in the python, it's inside the javascript:

```js
document.getElementById('loginForm').onsubmit = function() {
                        event.preventDefault()
                        event.stopImmediatePropagation()
                        fetch("/login", {
                            method: "POST",
                            body: {
                              redirect: document.getElementById('redirectlogin').value,
                              username: document.getElementById("typeUserX-2").value,
                                password: document.getElementById("typePasswordX-2").value
                            },
                            headers: {
                              "Content-type": "multipart/form-data;"
                            }
                            
                          })
                          .then((response) => response.json())
                            .then((json) => {
                                if (json.success) {
                                    // refresh page
                                    window.location.href = window.location.href
                                } else {
                                    document.getElementById('loginError').style.display = 'block'
                                    loginError.hidden = false
                                    document.getElementById('loginErrorMessage').innerHTML = json.message
                                }
                            });
                            console.log(JSON.stringify({
                              redirect: document.getElementById('redirectlogin').value,
                              username: document.getElementById("typeUserX-2").value,
                                password: document.getElementById("typePasswordX-2").value
                            }))

                    }
                })
```

I know it's this because after hours of testing, and using postman, I've found the problem to be the headers, as postman worked just fine, until I removed the content-type header. `multipart/form-data;` seems fine, but it's the lack of the boundaries header. I'm not familiar with headers.

I looked up this problem. They say to not specify any headers. The problem is, after I remove the headers, it defaults to text/plain.

Comment: this isnt how you send multipart form data ... see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects... generally it is easier to send json body payloads using javascript .... but then you would have to change the endpoint to accept that